# Find max common sum of subsets of 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given 2 Arrays of Intergers (unsorted, may contains duplicate elements), e.g.:

```
int[] left = {1, 5, 3};
int[] right = {2, 2};
```

We can get sums of subset of left array by picking or not picking up each element (2^n combinations), so, all the possbile sums could be (remove the duplicate sums):

```
{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9}
```

Same thing to the right array, sums of subset of right array are:

```
{0, 2, 4}
```

Then, the max common sum of subsets of these 2 arrays is 4, because 4 = left[0] + left[2] = rihgt[0] + right[1] and it's the max.

Question: how to get max common sum and indexes to construct this sum from 2 arrays? (if there are multipe combinations could get the same max sum in one array, just need to return one combination) Any better way to get the max common sum without caculating out all the possbile sums of subset?

Comment: " (2^n combinations)" .. and n is 1,2,3,4 ... or 0,1,2,3.. ? | and 0 is not a element in the array.. it shouldn't be part of "sums of subset"... right?

Comment: Here the n is length of the array, for example, if there are 3 elements in the array, then count_of_subset = 2^3 which is 8. Imaging that, for every element in the array, you have 2 choices: either put it into subset or not, so you'll get 2^n combinations, and 0 is the sum when you choose 0 element to build the subset. Hope this make it more clear.

Comment: What is optimal depends on the data. Do your arrays tend to have similar lengths and normally include at least a few small values? Is one array normally significantly longer than the other? Do they both normally contain similar values, or does one array tend to have large values and another array tend to have small values? For each different profile a different algorithm would be better, even to the point that using an algorithm on an unsuitable profile can lead to it taking longer than a brute force approach.

Comment: To demonstrate; one optimisation is to exclude any individual value that is larger than the sum of the other set. In your example above `5 > sum({2,2})`, so exclude the 5 from any approach you take. But, if your sets tend to be long and the values tend to be small, you'll rarely find such a value to exclude; thus you normally would have been better off not bothering, you took longer by trying to optimise for the wrong characteristic.

Comment: Also, what result do you want if there are multiple solutions. `{1,1,2,3,4}` and `{2,2}` has a max common sum of `4`, but the first array has 4 different subsets that total `4`, so which indices should be returned?

Comment: @MatBailie, length of these 2 arrays suppose to be very close, and contains similar value. You are right, if 1 element is greater that total sum of anther array, then it's useless and should be removed. And if there are multiple solutions, return any indices would be OK, but if we can return the indices contains most elements would be much better.

Comment: @Matbailie, Actually, the basic requirement for real world is to remove as much common part from 2 arrrys as possible. In you example, {1,1,2,3,4} and {2,2}, one approach is remove '2' both from left and right array, and then foucs on {1,1,3,4} and {2} only.

Comment: That's a fundamentally different problem than you origianlly described.  If you have `{1,2,3}` and `{2,2}` then remove a `2` from each, you get `{1,3}` and `{2}` which have no common sum.  So, please think carefully about your requirement and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, when you say "remove as much common as possible" do you mean as many elements as possible, or the highest total value possible?  They're not the same requirement.  For example `{3,3,3,10}` and `{9,13}` could remove `{3,3,3}` and `{9}` (as many elements as possible) ***or*** `{3,10}` and `{13}` (highest total value possible).

Comment: Oh, my bad, you are right, we cannot remove the same element at first and caculate the rest; if we do so, we may lose the optimal solution. I'd stick to my original description about the problem.

Comment: Does the elements of the array have any constraints? Like maximum possible sum is 10^6 or something?

Comment: @xjufo - Integers can be non-positive; how about your elements?

Comment: @risingStark Maxmun length of the array should less than 1,000, and each interger is less than 10,000.

Comment: @Armali Only positive elements in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution using bitsets in C++ will work.

```
// returns maximum possible common subset sum
int fun(int left[], int right[]){
    // for the given constraints, the maximum possible sum is 10^7
    bitset<10000001> b, b1;
    int n = // size of left array
    int m = // size of right array
    b[0] = b1[0] = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        b|=b<<left[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        b1|=b1<<right[i];
    }

    // After the above loop, b and b1 contains all possible unique values of subset sum.
    // Just loop from the most significant bit and find the position in which the
    // bits of both, b and b1 are set.
    // That position is the maximum possible common subset sum
    // For indices, any standard algorithm for finding subset-sum
    // for a particular sum will do.
}
```

Comment: I think, after the above loops, the bitsets contain rather all (unique) values of the respective array than all possible sums, as there is no summing up anywhere.

Comment: @Armali Yeah you are right. It contains all the unique possible subset sums.

Comment: This is not what I wrote; on the contrary, I think it contains no _sums_ at all.

Comment: @Armali Why do you think so. You could have just dry run it once. I found the link from which I understood this technique. You can read it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-queries-using-bitset/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's a clever technique. I now think that your suggestion (with the missing `|` added) is good.

Comment: @Armali Thank you very much. I seriously did not realise the first time that I had missed a `|`. I have edited the above answer all thanks to you and your constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the method pointed out by risingStark for finding the maximum common sum and on [Print all subsets with given sum](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perfect-sum-problem-print-subsets-given-sum/) for finding indexes of summands, and since the question uses Java syntax, here's an unoptimized and unbeautified Java program with some example data sets:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class _68232965
{
    static int sum;
    static boolean found;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        { int[][] lr = { {1, 5, 3},   {2, 2} }; maxcommsum(lr); }
        { int[][] lr = { {1,1,2,3,4}, {2, 2} }; maxcommsum(lr); }
        { int[][] lr = { {1, 2, 3},   {2, 2} }; maxcommsum(lr); }
        { int[][] lr = { {3,3,3,10},  {9,13} }; maxcommsum(lr); }
    }
    static void maxcommsum(int[][] lr)
    {
        for (var a: lr) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        var s = new BigInteger[] { BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE };
        for (int j, i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < lr[i].length; ++j) s[i] = s[i].shiftLeft(lr[i][j]).or(s[i]);
        while (s[0].bitLength() != s[1].bitLength())
        {   // find the maximum common sum
            int larger = s[0].bitLength() < s[1].bitLength() ? 1 : 0;
            s[larger] = s[larger].clearBit(s[larger].bitLength()-1);
        }
        sum = s[0].bitLength()-1;
        System.out.println("sum = "+sum);
        for (var a: lr) { found = false; f(a, 0, 0); System.out.println("<= indexes"); }
    }
    static void f(int[] pat, int i, int currSum)
    {   // find indexes of summands
        if (currSum == sum)
        {
            found = true;
            return;
        }
        if (currSum < sum && i < pat.length)
        {
            f(pat, i+1, currSum + pat[i]); if (found) { System.out.print(i+" "); return; }
            f(pat, i+1, currSum);
        }
    }
}
```